# Storing map types in DynamoDb, is "M" declaration required?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, fastapi

Using Boto3, how can I store python dictionaries as non-PK attributes in DynamoDb?

My CDK

```js
...
    this.table = new Table(this, `myTable`, {
      partitionKey: {
        name: 'id',
        type: AttributeType.STRING,
      },
    });
...
```

When I try to post requests to my API (using FastAPI), I get an empty error message.

API method

```py
@app.post('/create-student/{student_id}')
def create_student(student_id : int, student : Student):
    try:        
        response = db.put_item(Item={
            "id": f"{student_id}",
            "student": json.dumps(student)
        })
        return {"response message": response}            
    
    except Exception as error: 
        return {"error message": error}
```

Because the error message is returning, put_item method cannot be completed.

Two mitigations I see:

1. Dump the Python dictionary as a string (`json.dumps(dict)`) and insert this string
2. Add the student field in CDK to explicitly have type "M" for map.

Perhaps option 2 is necessary if I don't want to store the dict as a string. It seems that Ddb cannot store map types "out of the box" is this use case is not declared in CDK.

What's the preferred means to accomplish this effect?

Comment: The answer below is bang on. Be sure to familiarise yourself with the different clients and if you should use descriptors or not: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/

Answer (score 0):

As long as your secondary attributes are not parts of any indexes, DynamoDB doesn't really care what you put in them. It doesn't look like you're defining any attributes in CDK, so you should be good.

Assuming that `db` in your Python code is a reference to a Table resource, and you want the attribute `student` to be a Map in DynamoDB, you should pass a dictionary (or any other instance of [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping)):

```
db.put_item(Item={
            "id": f"{student_id}",
            "student": {"name": "John", "last_name": "Smith}
        })
```

If you `Student` type does not subclass `Mapping`, you should somehow convert it to a mapping.

By passing `json.dumps(student)`, you make it a string containing a JSON text.

Since you are saying that your code is throwing an error, it's possible that your variable `student` cannot be serialized as a JSON. But that's not you wanted in the first place anyway.